# AngularJS How to get the key value when the for loop wrap a http.get

Tags: angularjs, http

Here is the factory:

```
    myApp.factory('httpq', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    get: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.jsonp.apply(null, arguments)
      .success(deferred.resolve)
      .error(deferred.resolve);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the controller, httpq.get(url) wrap a for(var key in items.data) and another httpq.get(url2), how to get the key in httpq.get(url2)?

```
      $scope.items = [];
  $scope.page = 1;
  var url=BASE_URL+'&count=10&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
console.log('url: '+url);

    httpq.get(url)
    .then(function(items) {
       $scope.items=items.data;
//console.log('httpq:# ');
       for(var key in items.data)
       {
          var url2=BASE_URL+'&count=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
          console.log('url2: '+key+','+url2);

          httpq.get(url2)
          .then(function(items2) {
             console.log('it always displays 9: #'+key);
          })
          .catch(function(data, status) {
            console.error('2:Gists error', data, status);
          })
          .finally(function() {
            console.log("2:finally finished gists");
          });
       }

    })
    .catch(function(data, status) {
      console.error('1:Gists error', data, status);
    })
    .finally(function() {
      console.log("1:finally finished gists");
    });
```

it always displays '9' in httpq.get(url2)....

Any help would be much appreciated. Best Regards.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do it like that:

```
httpq.get(url2)
.then((function(key) {
  return function(items2) {
    console.log('it always displays 9: #'+key);
  };
})(key))
.catch(function(data, status) {
  console.error('2:Gists error', data, status);
})
.finally(function() {
  console.log("2:finally finished gists");
});
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I edited my answer because I forgot 2 parentheses aroung the function in the first `.then()`.

Comment: weird!! I didn't set the downvote, maybe the system do that, and the question is solved now, thanks.

Comment: @DinDin You can add the correct answer here which may help others or upvote the answer, if it exists here.

Comment: Yes, I use the answer from maxdec, and it works now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve it.
One,
Move the lines in the for loop to a separate function and pass key, BASEURL as arguments. In the for loop, just call that function in each iteration. It will solve the issue.

Second,

```
for(var key in items.data)
       {
         function(key){
          var url2=BASE_URL+'&count=1&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
          console.log('url2: '+key+','+url2);

          httpq.get(url2)
          .then(function(items2) {
             console.log('it always displays 9: #'+key);
          })
          .catch(function(data, status) {
            console.error('2:Gists error', data, status);
          })
          .finally(function() {
            console.log("2:finally finished gists");
          });
         }(key); // pass the values you need to access in the $http request
       }
```